# Isomorphism of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb R$

Tags: order-theory

How to prove that the set $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ with lexicographic order is not isomorphic with $\mathbb R$ with linear order?
I know I have to show that there is no such functions $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ which is an isomorphism but I dont't know how to write this proof.

Comment: Perhaps show that there is a nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ with no least upper bound.

Comment: @GEdgar but how to start this proof and how is it connected with that there is no isomorphism function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two isomorphic ordered sets share all properties that can be expressed in the language of ordered sets.

For instance, if $f\colon X\to Y$ is an order isomorphism and $A$ is a subset of $X$, then $A$ has a least upper bound if and only if $f(A)$ has a least upper bound.

Also, $A$ is upper bounded if and only if $f(A)$ is upper bounded.

Exercise: prove the two statements above.

Now, can you find a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ that's upper bounded but has no least upper bound? If $f\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an isomorphism, can you find a contradiction?

Comment: Is it good example to take a subset $A=\lbrace{\langle a,b\rangle\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} | a=0, b\in\mathbb{R} \rbrace}$ and then it has for example upper bound equal to $\langle1,0\rangle$ but has no least upper bound (because we can always find a better upper bound)

Comment: @avan1235 That's a fine example.

Comment: How can I try to show that two isomorphic ordered sets share all properties which can be expressed in the language of ordered sets?

Comment: @avan1235 That's not an easy problem to formulate (but then easy to prove); be content of proving it for specific properties like the ones I suggested.